# Alert on direct root logins

Tags: centos, console

We do not allow direct root logins through ssh but obviously through console access. Is it possible to log direct root logins and maybe send an email or write to a logfile if someone logins through console using root?

We use Centos 5/6

Comment: Is processing the output of the 'who' or 'last' command (/var/log/wtmp) an option for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux login process is primarily ruled by [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html) (Pluggable Authentication Modules for Linux) which is a suite of shared libraries that enable the local system administrator to choose how applications authenticate users.

By default some PAM  messages are already logged to syslog so by monitoring that you can trigger notifications. Specifically login events are logged to `/var/log/secure` by default. You can monitor this file for your alerts.

Alternatively you can use [**`pam_exec`**](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) to have a specific notification command executed as part of a successful login event.

```
session [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0
session required pam_exec.so /usr/bin/wall "root has logged in!"
```